# Convert UTC timestamp to readable format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this date format:

```
"Mon Jun 5 00:00:00 UTC-04:00 2017"
```

How can I convert it to any human-readable format?

Comment: this is in string?

Comment: what do you call a human readable format? something with a dial ?

Comment: @HWSiew, yes this is string

Comment: @MisterJojo, yes. something with a dial.

Comment: example of human-readable format of this?

Comment: I like moment.js for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: @HWSiew something like this: YYYY/MM/DD 12:00AM or DD-MONTH-YYYY 12:00AM

Comment: you certainly need SVG for that https://github.com/search?q=javascript+svg+clock  ...

Comment: What is not "human readable" about that date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what format you want you can use the JavaScript Date object. Documentation of other methods found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
let date = new Date("Mon Jun 5 00:00:00 UTC-04:00 2017");
console.log(date.toString());
console.log(date.toDateString());
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps

```js
var str = "Mon Jun 5 00:00:00 UTC-04:00 2017";

var date = new Date(str);
console.log(date);

var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
var hour = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

var output = `Year: ${year}/${month}/${year}  Time: ${hour}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;

console.log(output);
```